# MySQL search for exact match

Tags: mysql

I would like to search for exact match in SQL:

In searchString column  in  user table, I have :

```
alan@xxx.com 654433 active other text
ted@xsdd.com 43434 inactive other text
```

I would like to search for active or inactive only:

```
SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.searchString = 'active'
```

or

```
SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.searchString = 'inactive'
```

But it returns both the 2 rows for either of statements.

Expected result:

searchString = 'active' to return alan@xxx.com row only

searchString = 'inactive' to return ted@xsdd.com row only

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Your queries, as written, will do exactly what you intend. Either the data doesn't meet the criteria or you've not posted the correct queries. It is an impossibility that an exact match on 'active' will return a row with 'inactive' and vice-versa. It appears that the data you posted and the queries are samples, not exactly what you are using in your database. Please post actual code and actual sample data.

Answer (score 1):

use `like` operator with `OR` condition

```
SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.searchString like '%active%' 
   or u.searchString like '%inactive%'
```

Comment: Sorry. I was not clear. I have edited my post. I want to return either 1 only. please help. Thanks.

Comment: if some string contains 'inactive' word it would match to %active% so no reason to include like '%inactive%' in where clause. However, if some record contains 'semi-active' it would be matched (incorrectly?) with %active% too so I would not do such search.